# PHP: Check URL to select icon

Tags: php

i have variable ( `$URL` ) that return me URL.

So i need to check this URL if the URL is like (`www.facbook.com/ddddd`) get me icon of Facebook, If the URL is like (`www.twitter.com/ddddd`) get me icon of twitter ....

i try this way

```
 if($URL == 'www.facbook.com/ddddd')
    {
    $icon = 'fb.png';
    }
```

I hope I provided enough info, and would be cool if you went easy on me, this is a first project I'm learning on.

How can do that

Thank you!

Comment: `i try this way ` And what? It didn't work? or what?

Comment: You need to use Facebook API and also Twitter's, your other option is using cURL

Comment: its not work with me

Comment: `var_dump($URL)` may help